# How to protect the loaded json file name and location using html5 and javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, json, html, leaflet

The data of markers (not the map) is stored in a json/csv/js file. We want to show all data as markers on the map. But how to protect the raw data file from public access?

Following the example on leaflet website, the name and location of the data file is currently visible as plain text in the index.html. Any people can download them after viewing the source code of the html.

Is there any way to secure our raw data from public access?

for example, by encoding the file name and location and there is no way to decode it?

Or use some authorization method, tokenization, oAuth, RestFul API?

Or using PHP instead of html?

Any tips and suggestions are greatly welcome!

**EDIT:** 
How do the following websites handling the data? There is no seemingly data loaded by looking at their html file.

http://www.npr.org/censusmap

maps.huge.info/zip.htm and city-data.com/zipmaps/Austin-Texas.html

**EDIT2:**

For the place one user clicked, it is okay to release that specific place of information. But the detailed information about the rest of the world should be kept hidden.

How does Google Map protect its POI's?

For example, when we click a place

https://www.google.com/maps/place/UN+Plaza/@37.7778533,-122.4178577,16z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x0000000000000000:0xd80e268400cfc7ea

We can load the information about that place only. One cannot download a file from Google that contains all POI information about the world.

Comment: Who are you trying to hide the data from? If the map is publicly available, so is the data. Do you want to put it behind a login (OAuth, or your own PHP login?)

Comment: @nathancahill OP updated. I don't want to put it behind a login. The  markers on the map should be publicly visible, but not the raw data file name and location.

Comment: Not possible. Why are you worried about the raw data? The markers will be publicly visible on the map.

Comment: @nathancahill The access to the database of a web server should be protected. There should be a way.

Comment: Database? Not json/csv/js file?

Comment: @nathancahill The json/csv/js file serves as a database role for the http web server. That's why we want to protect it.

Comment: As I see it then, the problem is not the security of the data itself but in protecting co-hosted services from a ddos if people start using your data feed? I think its time to review your systems architecture instead. :)

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. You can [obfuscate](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/obfuscate) the data if you want by, for instance, using [TileMill](https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/) to render it into interactive tiles, but generally speaking, in order to communicate information you must reveal information.

Comment: How about these three websites? I dind't find any visible file name for their data. http://www.npr.org/censusmap and http://maps.huge.info/zip.htm and http://www.city-data.com/zipmaps/Austin-Texas.html @nathancahill

Comment: Those sites are serving up the data as images such as with TileMill as is the suggestion you're replying to! Even then any GIS/ESRI developer worth their salt can convert the data from the images in those links back to usable data tables. You cannot do what you are proposing. Once on the internet, always on the internet.

Comment: TileMile seems discontinued. And now it is replaced by Mapbox Studio. One quick question. Is it required to upload our data to Mapbox server?